# Why is my code-behind event handler not referenced?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, code-behind, autoeventwireup

Why does my code-behind have no effect and my breakpoint is not reached?

I've got this in my WebForm1.aspx file:

```
<asp:checkbox id="ckbxAllGenres" runat="server" Checked="True" OnCheckedChanged="ckbxAllGenres_CheckedChanged" />
<label for="ckbxAllGenres">All</label>
<asp:checkbox id="ckbxAction" runat="server" />
<label for="ckbxAction">Action</label>
<asp:checkbox id="ckbxAdventure" runat="server" />
<label for="ckbxAdventure">Adventure</label>
```

The event handler in WebForm1.aspx.cs file is:

```
protected void ckbxAllGenres_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool allGenresChecked = ckbxAllGenres.Checked;
    ckbxAction.Checked = allGenresChecked;
    ckbxAdventure.Checked = allGenresChecked;
    . . .
```

I have a breakpoint on the first line (the assignment to the bool).

The breakpoint is not reached when I check the ckbxAllGenres control; and so, of course, the code does not run, and nothing happens.

It's true that the event handler indicates "0 references," but why would that be?

The top line of WebForm1.aspx is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Flix4Fams_WebForms.WebForm1" %>
```

Comment: Did you observe a postback occurring at all when you clicked on the checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a year since I've used web forms, but I think you're missing `AutoPostBack="true"` on the checkbox:

```
<asp:checkbox 
    id="ckbxAllGenres" 
    runat="server" 
    Checked="True" 
    OnCheckedChanged="ckbxAllGenres_CheckedChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="true" />
```