# Why is my radiobutton asp code getting an "Invalid postback or callback argument"?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, rendering, html-rendering

Why is my radiobutton asp code failing with "Invalid postback or callback argument" even though I have added the steps that worked with the checkbox controls?

In a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64177843/why-is-my-code-behind-event-handler-not-referenced), I eventually incorporated a threefold approach to solve a problem of my code-behind not being called. The steps were these:

1. Incorporating the accepted answer there by adding this (AutoPostBack="true") to the checkboxes like so:

   <asp:checkbox id="ckbxAllGenres" runat="server" Checked="True" class="genres" OnCheckedChanged="ckbxAllGenres_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
   All
2. Adding EnableEventValidation="true" to the to of the Page so that it became this:

   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="true" Inherits="Flix4Fams_WebForms.WebForm1" %>
3. Overriding the Render method in the code-behind file, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764875/se-the-clientscriptmanager-registerforeventvalidation-method-in-order-to-registe) like so:

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
// Register controls for event validation
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(
c.UniqueID.ToString());
}
base.Render(writer);
}

That worked perfect with the Checkbox controls as shown above, but now that I have gotten to the radiobuttons, I get a similar exception as I was before with the checkboxes prior to making those changes, namely:

> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event
> validation is enabled using  in
> configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
> For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to
> postback or callback events originate from the server control that
> originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
> ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
> register the postback or callback data for validation.]
> System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
> String argument) +9830282
> System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String
> eventArgument) +114
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton.LoadPostData(String postDataKey,
> NameValueCollection postCollection) +77
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String
> postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +15
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData,
> Boolean fBeforeLoad) +471
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +1897

Prior to getting this error (when it was working), the radiobutton code was this:

```
<input type="radio" id="rdbtnAllIMDB" />
<label for="rdbtnAllIMDBA" class="marginR20">All</label>
<input type="radio" id="rdbtnGOE" checked="checked" />
<label for="rdbtnGOE">>= </label>
<input type="number" step="0.1" value="7.5" />
```

Now it is this, with a similar type of morphing:

```
<asp:radiobutton name="imdb" id="rdbtnAllIMDB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<label for="rdbtnAllIMDBA" class="marginR20">All</label>
<asp:radiobutton name="imdb" id="rdbtnGOE" Checked="True" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<label for="rdbtnGOE">>= </label>
<asp:textBox runat="server" type="number" AutoPostBack="true" step="0.1" value="7.5" />
```

Why did the changes I made get the Checkboxes to work, but it doesn't work with the radiobuttons? What do I need to do yet to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that for the RadioButtons to be mutually exclusive, they had to both have the same Name value (but different ID values).

Apparently the person was talking about the GroupName property (which does make sense), as when I changed the code to the following it worked:

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="imdbGroup" id="rdbtnAllIMDB" runat="server" />
<label for="rdbtnAllIMDBA" class="marginR20">All</label>
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="imdbGroup" id="rdbtnGOE" Checked="True" runat="server" />
```